# Can I get my UWP app to run automatically when the user logs in (eg by adding it to the Registry)?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I have a Windows Store Desktop App with which I try to write to the registry with the following pattern in order to have my app start automatically whenever the user logs in:

```
// The path to the key where Windows looks for startup applications
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
// Add the value in the registry so that the application runs at startup
rkApp.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

This goes on without any error displayed to the user. And the key is not written to the registry. I test this by sideloading the package. If I test it with the actual executable of the application it works OK.

Any hints?

NOTE: The desktop application is not converted to UWP using desktop bridge technology. It is being published with fullTrust capability.

EDIT: As the accpeted answer below states - the solution for this particular problem - making the application run on windows start is by creating a startupTask. An example for this can be found here:

https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridge/tree/master/Extras/StartupTask

Comment: Did you try to convert your desktop application to UWP app by [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) technology?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT No. I added a comment about this.

Comment: I'm confused about your desktop application. You said you have a windows store desktop app. But, only the UWP app and converted desktop app can be published to windows store, the converted desktop app actually also is an UWP app.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I guess VS 2017 does this automatically. You just create a publishing project for the desktop app.

Comment: What did you mean about 'publish project'?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT it's a separate project type that you create in the solution in order to publish a desktop app to the store.

Comment: Did you mean that it's a 'Windows application Packaging Project'?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Yes

Comment: This project is used to package your desktop application to UWP app. So, your question is clear. What you said 'windows store desktop app' actually is a converted desktop app. Then, please check the '**Your application modifies the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM) registry hive**' section of the [Prepare to package a desktop application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) document, you would know the reason why you face this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret the key you are writing to, what you really want is a way to launch your application at startup.  You can do this for UWP apps and Desktop Bridge apps by adding support for the windows.StartupTask extension.

See the following links:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask

Comment: Brilliant!   I didn’t know that all Win Store apps could now launch automatically at Windows startup!

Answer (score 3):

This is by design for packaged applications. The write operation does not go to the global registry, but to local one that is specific to the app and the user.

If you do a read operation after you written to your registry you will get the correct value, but other apps/process in the system won't see your changes to the registry.

The details of this are documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#registry